# How to extract body from email

Tags: c#, imap

Here is my code I am trying to get body of the email from textdata property but it is giving error object reference not set to instance of an object I dont have a clue what to do

```
      IMAPConfig config = new IMAPConfig("imap-mail.outlook.com","name@hotmail.com", "password", true, true, "");

        config.CacheFile = "";

        IMAPClient client = null;

            client = new IMAPClient(config, null, 5);

            IMAPFolder f = client.Folders["Inbox"];
            //  Console.WriteLine(f.GetMessageByID(7049)) ;

            int[] msgCount = null;

            while (msgCount == null || msgCount.Length == 0)
            {
                msgCount = f.CheckForNewMessages();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            foreach (int id in msgCount)
            {
                IMAPMessage msg = f.GetMessageByID(id);
                string a = null;
                a = msg.TextData.TextData;
                //MessageBox.Show(msg.TextData.ToString());
                msg.MarkAsRead();
            }
```

Comment: a = msg.TextData.TextData;   shouldnt it be something else it is the same property twice?

Comment: By debugging I have checked that msg.textdata.textdata is retrieving the body of email thats why i have tried that

Comment: @Andreas Any other way you know to get body of email so plz tell me.

Comment: try msg.Body ..hope it will help

Comment: @Sachu there is no property called body exist in msg object

Comment: @HishamShahid try `if(msg.TextData.TextData != null){a=....}` OR `if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msg.TextData.TextData)){a=...}`

Comment: @sachu These conditions are not fulfilling same error object reference not set to instance of an object

Comment: @HishamShahid any inner exception or details available when u use try catch?

Comment: can you cast it to MailMessage instead of IMAPMessage  ?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as how InterIMAP is a dead project, I would highly recommend switching to [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which is not only actively maintained (by me), but also has a lot more features (I mean, InterIMAP's home page says it will get support for copying messages *soon* and hasn't been updated since 2009), has a lot more users, and a lot fewer bugs. It's also a lot easier to use.

For example, here's how you would do what you are trying to do with MailKit:

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("imap-mail.outlook.com", 993, true);
    client.Authenticate ("name@hotmail.com", "password");

    client.Inbox.Open (FolderAccess.ReadWrite);

    for (int i = 0; i < client.Inbox.Count; i++) {
        var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage (i);
        var html = message.HtmlBody;
        var text = message.TextBody;

        // mark the message as read
        client.Inbox.AddFlags (id, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
    }

    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

I've also got MSDN-style documentation (that I'm always working on improving) at http://www.mimekit.net/docs that you might find helpful. If you have any questions, my email address can be found on the github project page (the "MailKit" link at the top of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using InterIMAP for this. If you look at the source code for `IMAPMessage.TextData` (https://interimap.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#InterIMAP/InterIMAP/Objects/IMAPMessage.cs) you can see that it will return null if there is no plain text body part in the message.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The content of the message as plain text (if available)
    /// </summary>
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IMAPMessageContent TextData
    {
        get 
        { 
            //RefreshData(true, false); 
            foreach (IMAPMessageContent content in _bodyParts)
            {
                if (content.ContentType.ToLower().Contains("plain"))
                    return content;
            }
            return null;
        }
        //set { _textData = value; }
    }
```